# Is it possible to use the network stack of a different container in the same task on an AWS ECS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, docker-network

I want to run two containers in one ECS task.

Container 1 should run with the default docker network mode `bridge`.

Container 2 should use the network stack of the first container. With docker run, this is done like `docker run --network container:container1 container2`.

I don't see any possibility to set this in the CloudFormation template, since there the network mode is specified for the whole task only.

I already tried running everything on my local environment, i.e. `docker run` both containers after each other. This works nicely.

I couldn't try anything with AWS, since I don't know where I can define the network modes that I want to have. I read following documentations:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-networkmode
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings

Sadly, nothing was pointing me into the direction that I want to go with my setup.

Does anyone have an idea on how this could work? Is this even possible/intended to do on AWS? What are the alternatives then?

---

Edit

What do I want to achieve? Container1 should run a VPN. Therefore I run a container that is able to connect to a VPN provider during its startup.

Container2 uses the network stack of container1, i.e. its running through the VPN of container1.

Comment: AWS ECS does not support different network mode per container. If you could describe what you are actually trying to accomplish, there may be another way to do this in ECS.